# Show overlay menu by checking a checkbox

Tags: html, css

I want to show the overlay menu by checking the checkbox (class "hamburger-checkbox"). The problem is that after checking the checkbox the overlay menu doesn't disappear (check line 154 in CSS) even the code is the same as for the hamburger menu animation (e. g. line 149 in CSS):

**Link to CodePen:** https://codepen.io/matu-sk/pen/ZEJrypw

**Code:**

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
      <input class="hamburger-checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <div class="hamburger-bun">
        <div class="hamburger-burger">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay-menu">
    <div class="overlay-nav-wrapper">
      <ul class="nav overlay-nav">
        <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">a</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">b</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #04080f;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

/** NAVIGATION **/

nav {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 502px;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #04080f;
}

.overlay-menu {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 155px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 3em;
}

.overlay-nav-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay-nav a:hover {
  color: #424CF9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    margin: auto;
  }
}

/** HAMBURGER MENU **/

.hamburger-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hamburger-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-bun:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #04080f;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0, 1.2);
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-bun:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #04080f;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0, 1.2);
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-bun .hamburger-burger {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-bun .hamburger-burger:before, .hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-bun .hamburger-burger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #04080f;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0, 1.2);
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:hover ~ .hamburger-bun:before, .hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:hover ~ .hamburger-bun:after, .hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:hover ~ .hamburger-bun :before, .hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:hover ~ .hamburger-bun :after {
  background: #424CF9;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:checked ~ .hamburger-bun:before, .hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:checked ~ .hamburger-bun:after {
  width: 0;
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:checked ~ .hamburger-bun .hamburger-burger:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:checked ~ .hamburger-bun .hamburger-burger:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
}

.hamburger-wrapper .hamburger-checkbox:checked ~ .overlay-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what action/event should get rid of the menu. Is it when the checkbox is clicked again?

Comment: In the final version, it will be done as you mentioned, but for simplicity, I exchanged it in the question. I have already solved the problem, but thank you for your willingness to help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way

```
<nav>
   <div class="hamburger-menu">
      <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
         <input type="checkbox" class="hamburger-checkbox"></input>
         <div class="hamburger-bun">
            <div class="hamburger-burger">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="overlay-menu">
            <div class="overlay-nav-wrapper">
               <ul class="nav overlay-nav">
                  <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">a</a></li>
                  <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">b</a></li>
                  <li><a class="nav-link-hidden" href="">c</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input has no closing tag. If you want the hamburger to toggle the checkbox, use `<label>`:

```
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hamburger-checkbox" id="hamburger-checkbox">
    <label for="hamburger-checkbox">
      <div class="hamburger-bun">
        <div class="hamburger-burger">
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can hide the checkbox, so only the `<label>` will be seen.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the input tag, but it didn't resolve my problem.